# I cannot call with Siri on whatsapp

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

After I update my iPhone 7 Plus with iOS 14 (14.0.1) my siri is not calling with whatsApp. I don't know what is the reason. I tried to make Shortcut but I cannot see action for call with whatsApp or also cannot see read messages with whatsApp.

It was working very well before I update iOS. Siri works very well with everything other than whatsApp. I contact whatsApp support and send them diagnostic log file, they reply me it is issue with Phone.

Kindly help me to resolve it, it is driving me nuts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you re-enabled Siri for WhatsApp? Go to settings and check under siri & search. Scroll down to whatsapp and check the box to allow "use with Ask Siri".

Comment: Yes it is done. lot of times